# How to Turn Leftover Minutes into Hours

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with two columns that count hours and minutes, respectively, with sums to totals at the bottom. I would like to make it so when the minutes reach sixty, it automatically subtracts sixty minutes and adds one hour to the total, that way I am not left with 4 hours and 346 minutes.

It currently looks like this:

```
Hours  Minutes
1        30
5        35
0        45
2        15
Total  Total
8        125
```

But I'd like it to look like this:

```
Hours   Minutes
1        30
5        35
0        45
2        15
Total   Total
10       05
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

With the following two formulas you can do that.

### Formula

```
Hours
=SUM(A2:A5) + HOUR(TIME(0,SUM(B2:B5),0))

alternate way of notation
=HOUR(TIME(SUM(A2:A5),SUM(B2:B5),0))

Minutes
=SUM(B2:B5) - (HOUR(TIME(0,SUM(B2:B5),0)) * 60)

alternate way of notation
=MINUTE(TIME(SUM(A2:A5),SUM(B2:B5),0))
```

### Explained

The hour calculation sums up the hour values and adds the sum of the minutes converted to hours. For the minutes, the calculation is a bit different. Here the sum of the minutes is subtracted by the hour count of those minutes, leaving only minutes ranging from 0 to 59.

In the second tab, the alternate formula is added.

### Screenshot

*Hours*
[image]

*Minutes*
[image]

### Note

Use a custom format (*Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format...*) to obtain a leading zero, see screenshot:
[image]

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[How to Turn Leftover Minutes into Hours](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iTDlLfLqbNGmcs6TB-2mcTOR4FRiZSdlifEN66pj1_E/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

in A7: `=sum(A2:A5)+int(sum(B2:B5)/60)` and
in B7: `=mod(sum(B2:B5),60)`